# Invoke Android Instant app from Chrome webpage

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Is there a way to invoke Android instant app directly from Chrome? Preferably bypassing this unnecessary step?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b6ju.png)

Comment: I wouldn't call that "unnecessary"...

Comment: Why is that? Covering the whole screen with a modal is not a good user experience. Apple handles this way better with a smaller modal that covers only a portion of the screen. Plus, why would there be an option to open in web? The whole purpose of deep links and instant apps is to get users to use native experience in a short or a full version if it. The adoption of instant apps compared to app clips is obviously behind, I could argue that this is one of the reasons why. There is 0 reason why the whole screen should be obstructed with this random poorly built UI.